# Quantum gates, an example

Tags: quantikz

I'm unable to type this in XeTeX:

[image]

Any hints ?

Comment: Use the package `quantikz`. [Its manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/quantikz/quantikz.pdf) contains examples similar to yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{quantikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}[row sep={5mm,between origins}]
  &\ctrl{1} & \qw \\
  &\ctrl{1} & \qw \\
  &\gate{U} & \qw
\end{quantikz}
\hspace{0.7em}=
\begin{quantikz}[row sep={5mm,between origins}]
  &\qw      & \ctrl{1} & \qw              & \ctrl{1} & \ctrl{2} & \qw \\
  &\ctrl{1} & \targ{}  & \ctrl{1}         & \targ{}  & \qw      & \qw \\
  &\gate{V} & \qw      & \gate{V^\dagger} & \qw      & \gate{V} & \qw 
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works fine, thank you! Does it matter to compile either with XeTeX or LaTeX ?

Comment: Easiest way to work it out: Try it. Then you will find that it doesn't matter.

Comment: @gernot For my humble opinion the code is perfect! :-) The sign "=" but it is not simmetric between the two drawing.

Comment: @Sebastiano Yeah, I noticed, too. But this is something for the OP to work out. Apparently, the quantikz pictures are not equally spaces on both sides.

Comment: @Sebastiano Well, now the picture is prettier, but the code is uglier.